# KotlinJs - simple HTTP GET without Dynamic Type functionality

Tags: http-get, kotlin-js

I'm totally new in KotlinJs and I wanted to check its potential in server-less service development.

I decided to start with **calling external API with HTTP GET** method using `XMLHttpRequest()` suggested in *KotlinJs* documentation. However, I cannot come up with any way of using it without `dynamic` mechanism.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

    var xhttp: dynamic = XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true)
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = fun() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
            println(xhttp.responseJson)
        }
    }
    xhttp.send()
}
```

Of course this example works perfectly fine, but I feel like **it has to be better way of doing it without disabling Kotlin's type checker**.

- **Is there any way of doing it using KotlinJs only (without dynamic) ?**
- **If it is not possible, could someone at least explain why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a way for not using dynamic with callbacks, just like in classic .js**

```
private fun getData(input: String, callback: (String) -> Unit) {

    val url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$input"
    val xmlHttp = XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url)
    xmlHttp.onload = {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4.toShort() && xmlHttp.status == 200.toShort()) {
            callback.invoke(xmlHttp.responseText)
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send()
}
```

and than just call it:

```
getData("1") {
    response -> println(response)
}
```

Hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Why don't you just use the fetch api? you can define it using the external keyword

Comment: Its actualy also good idea, however at that time I had been using this language few hours in total. Thanks for diffrent solution suggestion ;)

Comment: sure thing, If you need help defining the fetch api, I can write it down for you